# How can I get the full path to a file in Bat?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, filepath

There is such a problem. In a bat file, I need to display the path to a file: either from the current directory, or a file from Path.
Basically, everything works for me, but the script breaks when a relative path is written in the Path.
For example: here is Path: "a; C: \ dev". Both of these folders contain the 1.exe file. My script will display the following result:

```
C:\dev\1.exe
a\1.exe
```

and I need the full path to the file in the second line. I know that there are modifiers like %~dp1, but if the file name consists of several words, then I cannot use such a construction, since %~dp* does not work.
In general, the gist of the question: how to get the full path to a file in bat?
I wanted to use this:

```
set mac=%path%
:m1
if "%mac%" neq "" (
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%i in ("%mac%") do (
        if exist "%%i\%arg%" (
            set chunk="%%i"
            set chunk=%chunk:~2,2%
            if "%chunk%"==":\" (
                echo %%i\%arg%
            ) else (
                echo %~dp0\%%i\%arg%
            )
            set bool=1
        ) else (
            for %%a in (%pathext%) do (
                if exist "%%i\%arg%%%a" (
                    set chunk="%%i"
                    set chunk=%chunk:~2,2%
                    if "%chunk%"==":\" (
                        echo %%i\%arg%%%a
                    ) else (
                        echo %~dp0\%%i\%arg%%%a
                    )
                    set bool=1
                )
            )
        )
        set mac=%%j
        goto m1
    )
```

but it doesn't work :(
My task - to do analog of Where

Comment: You say that "the script breaks when a relative path is written in the Path", but you have not written one, even removing the invalid whitespace from the second semi-colon delimited string, all you've provided are a string, which may be the name of a file, or a directory, or neither; and an absolute path. I expect the parser to know what an absolute path is, and a relative path, but how you expect it to know that a single character is anytghing other than a very small string, is beyond my comprehension. If you entered it as a relative path, it would have looked more like this: `.\a; C:\dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your provided, but corrected example string `a; C:\dev`, and as you specifically mentioned in your comment, that the modifiers don't work, here's an example which show that they do:

```sh
@For %%G in (a; C:\dev) Do @Echo %%~fG
```

The above should show you that it adds the current directory to your first string, `a`, as a full path.

---

As an example, since you've not directly explained what your script is supposed to be doing, *(or included any of it in your question body)*, and given that your provided example string already contains invalid or additional spaces, if you have the following, `a;C:\dev`, then to return the names of all `.exe` files in those two locations as full paths, *(inserting the current directory as requested)*, I'd use this:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "a;C:\dev":"*.exe" 2>NUL
```

And similarly, if you were looking only for a file named `1.exe`:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe "a;C:\dev":"1.exe" 2>NUL
```

Comment: Thank you! `For %%G in (a; C:\dev) Do @Echo %%~fG` works fine!

Comment: @TheTerribleIvan A hint regarding to find a file in a directory listed in enviroment variable `PATH`: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and read the output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. You will also read about `%~$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH environment variable and expands %I to the fully qualified name of the first one found.` in the language of the operating system.